# My Site stuck on "We're almost ready!"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, mysite

Every time I visit the MySites of my on premise SharePoint 2013 site, I see "`We're almost ready!`" but I already have a My Site site collection.

A couple weeks ago, site collections stopped being created, and all new users are now seeing the same message. There is no error message saying there are any access issues.

I am able to see my documents that are in my My Site. I only see the `"We're almost ready!"` on the My Site Host and when I click on my newsfeed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please go into the **User Profile Service Application** in **Central Administration**.

- Go to Manage User Profiles.
- Search for the profile experiencing the issue.
- Modify the "Personal Site Capabilities" from the existing value to 14.
- Save the profile and wait a few minutes, then re-check your MySite.

Comment: This worked for my My Site, but new users site collections are still not being created. I am viewing the content databases screen in CA and the numbers are staying the same.

Comment: Rebooting the entire farm resolved whatever the issue was. Modifying the Personal Site Capabilities corrected my profile. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There are the couple of things which can cause this issue.

- check and make sure Distributed Cache is properly configured, up and running. check [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx)
- Check the Site Naming Format setting.Did the Site Naming Format setting set to “User Name (do not resolve conflict)”? check [this](https://sharepoint2013admin.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/258/)
- check my site host setting, check [this](http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2013/04/10/my-site-creation-stuck-at-were-almost-ready-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- check if the personal managed path exists. check this[enter link description here](http://jurisinnenad.blogspot.com/2015/09/my-site-creation-stuck-at-were-almost.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I just turned on "Self-Service Site Creation" on my My Site web application and that fixed the issue. Please refer to below link to turn on "Self-Service Site Creation" for a web application.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261685(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This issue actually re-occurred. It typically re-occurs after a patching. The previous solution was to reboot the servers but this time it did not work.

Form previous experience with the issue I am confident in saying checking the bullet points above

- Distributed cache is running. Any further messing with is playing with fire
- MYsites was previously working before updates
- same as above
- same as above

I am interested in why patching would cause mysites to pause. The mysite timer jobs that create them still run as normal but nothing gets created.